# Single request to call multiple backends in Datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

We have a requirement, a single input should go to multiple backends. For this, I am using Results action with context variable set as below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
exclude-result-prefixes="dp regexp"
extension-element-prefixes="dp" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:variable name="MultiResults">
<results mode="require-all" multiple-outputs="true">
<url>http://127.0.0.1:9988/MainLocation</url>
<url>http://127.0.0.1:4188/MainLocation</url>
</results>
</xsl:variable>
<dp:set-variable name="'var://context/uservars/resultURLs'" value="$MultiResults"/>
```

The issue I'm having is I don't see request going to any of the backends. I'm getting error "Dynamic backend Host" not specified. How can I send the single request to all the three backend services ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable `var://service/routing-url` if you have a dynamic backend. Depending on how you want your service to operate you can send one of the outputs to the `routing-url` and that will be triggered by the original `Result` and then add a second Result for the other destination.

IMO and especially if you need to be certain, and be able to handle errors, it is better to use a `dp:url-open()` to POST your data and validate the response from the url-open() and then just do a `skip-backside` with `var://service/mpgw/skip-backside = 1` (or set a "Set-Variable" Action anywhere in your Rule).

Comment: I Have used dp:url-open(), the request is getting routed to the backend services but in the probe for the router it's showing the outbound url same as inbound. In the logs I'm getting error :"Remote error on url". If I'm getting this error then how the request is reaching to backend ?